# Rectangle not moving when multiplied by delta time

Tags: java, delta

I'm trying to use delta to move a rectangle. However when I multiply it by the speed and add it to the rectangle x position, the rectangle does not move. I thought the problem might lie in the game loop, but I don't think this is it.
Here's the code:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//do double buffering

public class Game extends Canvas {
    int x, y;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int height = 400;
    public static final int width = height * 16 / 9;

    JPanel p;
    Game game;

    Image buffer;

    KeyListener kl;
    MouseListener ml;

    public boolean running = true;

    public Game(){
        kl = new KeyListener(){

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }
        };

        ml = new MouseListener(){

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        };
    }

    public void update(double delta){
        x += 10/1000 * delta;
    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null){
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run(){

        //initialize time loop variables
        long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
        final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
        final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
        double lastFpsTime = 0;

        //Main game loop
        while(running)
        {
            //Calculate since last update
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
            lastLoopTime = now;
            double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

            //update frame counter
            lastFpsTime += updateLength;

            //update FPS counter
            if(lastFpsTime >= 1000000000)
            {
                lastFpsTime = 0;
            }

            //game updates
            game.update(delta);

            //graphics (gameState)
            game.render();

            try{
                Thread.sleep((Math.abs(lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME)/1000000));
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error in sleep");
            }
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

        game = new Game();

        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.addKeyListener(kl);
        frame.addMouseListener(ml);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Game().start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `y` are integers and `10/1000 * delta` is most of the time less than 1. Incremeting `x` with such a value will not change `x` at all.

To fix this, try to change the type of `x` to `float` or `double`, and just use `Math.floor()` or just cast it to an `int` when drawing it:

```
g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue on the previous answer: 10/1000 will give you zero while 10./1000 will give you the real number that it represents. So you should change your statement to

x += (int)(10./1000 * delta);

and hopefully delta is some number greater than 1000/10 to raise this to an integer greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your x and y variables to be float or double.

```
double x, y;
```

And if you wish to see movement, you'll need to change to something like this...

```
x += 100d / 1000d * delta;
```

What you were doing before was dividing an integer 10 by an integer 1000 and getting 0 as a result.

You'll also need to cast the results to ints when you draw the rect...

```
g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 100, 100);
```